# Admitting a unique fixed point in math

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

I've noticed that some of my professors seem to like to use the term *admit* in the following sense (from the [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) theorem):   "If F is a contraction from a complete metric space to itself, then it admits a unique fixed point."

I'm curious as to the word choice/usage of the term *admit*. It seems to be equivalent in usage, at least here, to 'has', but I see it in quite a bit of formal math from certain professors.

Does it have a particular connotation/meaning that *has* doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mathematics I believe it means something more like

> to allow or concede as valid

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admit).

Comment: -1 So it does outside of mathematics. TFD says nothing of math. How does this answer the question?

Comment: +1 So it does inside of mathematics also.  As a mathematician, I can attest that this is current usage, dictionaries be damned.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. The OP's sentence with *admits* sounds natural to me, whereas "the contraction *F* allows a unique fixed point as valid" sounds like gibberish. (And likewise with "concedes".)

Comment: @ruakh then don't say it that way. "If F is a contraction, then it allows/has/admits a fixed point.".

Comment: @ruakh: Try "concedes a fixed point as valid." That would be the way the construction works.

Comment: @Robusto: As I said, I already tried it. "The contraction *F* concedes a unique fixed point as valid" sounds like gibberish to me.

Comment: @Mitch: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say. I'm saying that this definition doesn't seem to make sense, because it takes a word that makes sense and defines it as *not* making sense.

Comment: @ruakh English ain't math. Frankly, mathematical English ain't math either. There's all sorts of metaphors and figures of speech used in mathematical writing. Which is a long way to get to: dictionary words aren't (always) one-to-one replaceable with their definitions. Once dictionaries are specified so logically, the Singularity won't have much use for us organics.

Comment: @Mitch: Re: "dictionary words aren't (always) one-to-one replaceable with their definitions": That's true. And in fact, even in cases where *admit* actually *does* mean "to allow or concede as valid", the latter phrasing could be a bit awkward. ("I conceded the force of his argument as valid" is rather strange.) But surely a dictionary definition, in order to apply to a given sentence, must have *something* to do with the usage in that sentence. (Other than, "it's a definition for a different sense of the same word". ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In mathematics, 'admit' is often used in statements where a mere 'have' would do the job quite well, and the connotation that this word can bring in is that it is *nice* or *something of an achievement* that the object has the property (i.e., the object *admits* the property).

For example, in proof theory, one often hears that a calculus 'admits' [cut elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) ([example usage](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007207000644)). One might say 'has cut elimination' and it would convey the same fact (and is also often used), but 'admits' conveys the attitude of the speaker/community to cut elimination in that it is a very useful property for a calculus to have, it is inobvious that the calculus has it, and it is sometimes difficult to achieve. In a sequent calculus, *cut* is one of the derivation rules. Now proofs using cut can be nasty. *Cut elimination* is a procedure whereby a proof in that calculus that can in principle employ all of the derivation rules is transformed into another proof that makes do without the cut rule. Cut-free proofs tend to be nicer because they have the subformula property: each formula occuring in the proof is a subformula of the formula (sequent) to be proved. This facilitates proof search.

I believe that using 'admit' in your example is motivated analogously. It actually conveys two basic facts: that a fixed point exists *and* that it is unique. The [Wikipedia entry on contraction mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) has the following:

> A contraction mapping has at most one fixed point. Moreover, the Banach fixed point theorem states that every contraction mapping on a nonempty complete metric space has a unique fixed point, and that for any x in M the iterated function sequence *x, f (x), f (f (x)), f (f (f (x))), ...* converges to the fixed point. This concept is very useful for iterated function systems...

The existence of a fixed point, in this case, would be the strong or desirable property for the mapping to have.

Answer (score 2):

I think the connotation is that something admitted is something that is constructed, rather than emerging naturally as an inherent property.

Comment: That's an opinion, right?

Comment: Yes, it's an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

"Admission" in this sense connotes an idea that is ***conceded*** by way of a proof.